# How to Map DB fields that are not declared in java entity class but in the result set of the query?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I've the following entity class and User table with same columns  as below

```
public class User  {

@EmbeddedId
@Column(name="USER_ID") 
private String userId;

@Column(name="USER_EMAIL")
private String userEmail;
```

i am using the above entity class for both save and get user details from db and my get query is
`SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM regmgmt.user WHERE active_ind = 'A' ORDER BY last_edited_date DESC )  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY`  , i dynamically update OFFSet value.Now as per new get requirements i've to  get the user name which in user_details table  and also total count of User table.

```
public class UserDetails  {

     @EmbeddedId
     @Column(name="USER_ID") 
     private String userId;

     @Column(name="USER_NAME")
     private String userName; 
 }
```

unfortunately, i  can't make any changes to  user table and but i can make changes to entity User.class, until it doesn't effect the pagination ,save and delete functionalities.what i am trying to achieve is , inner join user and user detail tables with matching userids and also get total count of users using single query and map it to user.class

Comment: what is your count on exactly? Maybe show what you want, as it doesn't seem to relate to the query you've shown at all.

Comment: i need the count of total user records in user table,so that in UI i can show something like "showing 10 of total 50 users"

Comment: just do one count query separate from any others. The ui can issue it once, separately from the data fetches - there is no point checking the total on each and every page if it is mostly static data anyway.